# how can i keep track of "Ant Design- Dynamic Form Item" and store all values in a single object state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So I'm using Ant Design [Dynamic Form Item](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-dynamic-form-item) and you can create as many as input field you want.

the question is how can I store all of the values`(static field and new fields)` in a single `array of objects` inside my state?

[Please take a Look at my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geybW.png)

if you click add it will create another Autocomplete and a inputfield. and you enter data

for example I want an array of object like this

```
[{commisionFor: 'Invoicing' , perctange: 10},{newcondition: 'something' , percentage: 32},{} , {} , {] , and etc ]
```

I wanna achieve this. how can i do this ? I will appreciate your help

**PS**: I'm not typing my code here because it's to complex and I don't even know what i did. Take look at this Ant Design Dynamic Form Item sandbox

[Ant Dynamic Form Item CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z9clrx)

Comment: why don't you try onChange or onBlur with your input and assign value to object?

Answer (score 1):

you can use onChange event to store all values separately.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

const onChangeHandler = (name, value) =>{
   let data = values;
    data[name] = value;

   setValues(data)
}
```

and in your multiple input field, create unique name for each input field.

```
 fields.map((name, index) => {
    <Input placeholder={name} name={name} onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(name, e.target.value)} />
})
```

use your own attribute for naming fields or just use the index value.